# How to Transfer data to phone when size is greater than 4KB

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We need to transfer data to users mobile and in 60% cases the data is going to be greater than 4KB which is limiting us from using FCM - in that case is it a good idea to just notify the user through FCM and then it makes a REST call to server to pull new data?

And for remaining 40% where the data is less than 4KB we were planning to use FCM (Firebase Cloud messaging)

So a solution which is a mix of both FCM when data is less than 4KB and FCM+REST when data is greater than 4KB

Any points that I should consider while using this method on android and iOS

Comment: Would something like Retrofit be a good idea to pull data from server

Comment: you can push from server and then ask the client to get the data from the server whenever a push happens.

Comment: send some flag in the FCM, so if the flag is`true`, then the data is complete in FCM, and if false - then FCM contains a link to the data.

Comment: yes @VladMatvienko - even I was thinking on similar lines.